# Tensorflow 2.0 : pb to restore model and perform inference

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to modify the official [pix2Pix Tensorflow 2.0 tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/generative/pix2pix)  in order to save the generator's model and then be able to reload it and perform image generation (inference)

In order to do so, I have followed the example from ['Using the SavedModel format' tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/saved_model) This notebook code is executing fine, without any problem.

So basically I add at the end of the training loop, this code to save the generator's model to disk:

```
tf.saved_model.save(generator, checkpoint_dir + "/pix2pix/1/")
  print("\nGenerator model saved in {}/pix2pix/1/".format(checkpoint_dir))
```

And then, in order to reload the model and do inference I use this code:

```
def generate_images2(model, test_input, tar, debug=True):

  # Key name of the output layer in the model:
  key_name = list(model.structured_outputs.keys())[0]

  prediction = model(test_input)[key_name]
  if debug:
    print("Key name of the output layer in the model:", key_name)
    print("\nprediction:\n", prediction)

  plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))

  display_list = [test_input[0], tar[0], prediction[0]]
  title = ['Input Image', 'Ground Truth', 'Predicted Image']

  for i in range(3):
    plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1)
    plt.title(title[i])
    # getting the pixel values between [0, 1] to plot it.
    plt.imshow(display_list[i] * 0.5 + 0.5)
    plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()

checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'

loaded = tf.saved_model.load(checkpoint_dir + "/pix2pix/1/")
print("Load Model - signature keys:", list(loaded.signatures.keys()))

infer = loaded.signatures["serving_default"]
print("\nInference structure output:", infer.structured_outputs)


# Run the trained model on one exampel of the test dataset
for inp, tar in test_dataset.take(1):
  generate_images2(infer, inp, tar, debug=True)
```

The code runs without error but the output tensor from the inference step (based on the reloaded model) contains only NaN values. Here is the inference's output:

```
Load Model - signature keys: ['serving_default']

Inference structure output: {'conv2d_transpose_8': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='conv2d_transpose_8')}

Key name of the output layer in the model: conv2d_transpose_8

prediction:
 tf.Tensor(
[[[[nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   ...
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]]

  [[nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   ...
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]]

  [[nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   ...
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]]

  ...

  [[nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   ...
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]]

  [[nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   ...
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]]

  [[nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   ...
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]]]], shape=(1, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Did I miss something or is there an issue with Tensorflow 2.0. Any idea or suggestion ?

Currently, I would suspect that the way the model is built, by assembling together several Keras sequential models (as building-blocks) might cause issue with the model save/restore features. (Similarly, Tensorboard is also not able to display properly the graph of the model: each of the buidling block appears disconnected from the others)

Note:

- I am using Tensorflow GPU 2.0.0-rc1 with Python 3.6.8 (same issue with the rc0)
- Here is a [link to download the Jupyter notebook with the code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RWAzn-kG1WDc9gM3oqCbs3VWRl8_7iG2/view?usp=sharing) - This notebook allows to reproduce the problem without having to use a Kubeflow cluster
- Here is a [link to download the Jupyter Notebook saved as a HTML page, including the execution output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LznnHgHIqxZz-A7g59lGTijI_fPOtS7Y/view?usp=sharing)
- The model in this notebook requires a GPU with at least 16GB of memory